# How to store result of EXEC sys.sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exec

How can I store the result of `exec` into a variable?

Here's my attempt at storing the data in a variable:

```
DECLARE @oltp VARCHAR(50) SET @oltp = 'emp'
DECLARE @wh VARCHAR(25) SET @wh = '_wh'
DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME = @oltp + @wh;
DECLARE @oltp_data_days NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @vi int

SET @oltp_data_days = N'(SELECT datediff(DAY, MIN(business_date), GETDATE()) AS keep_days
        FROM '+QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)+'..sales 
        WHERE business_date > ''1/1/2000 00:00:00'')'

EXEC sp_executesql  @oltp_data_days  = @oltp_data_days
      , @Params = N'@vi INT OUTPUT'
      , @vi = @vi OUTPUT
```

I am getting results as Null.

Comment: `INSERT INTO...EXEC...`?

Comment: Also, what do we call you now, Anu or Mani? As this is clearly the  problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68377192/2029983) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68362440/2029983). Perhaps Anu is a class mate? If so I suggest maybe working together. If you created this an a second account to avoid a question ban, that is against the rules.

Comment: Also `EXEC sp_executesql  @oltp_data_days  = @oltp_data_days` will error. `sys.sp_executesql` doesn't have a parameter named `@oltp_data_days`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'set @vi = (select 3 as keep_days)'
declare @vi int

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@vi int output', @vi = @vi output

select @vi
```